# how to open app in android with deeplinking in expo

Tags: android, expo, deep-linking

I am trying to open my android app with deeplink in ios its working for me but in android i its not opening
my app.config.json

```html
 intentFilters: [
      {
        action: "VIEW",
        autoVerify: true,
        data: [
          {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "*./http://192.168.1.4:3000",
            pathPrefix: "/"
          },
          {
            scheme: "rentcreek",
            host: "*",
            pathPrefix: "/"
          }
        ],
        
        category: ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
      }
    ]
```

and my prefix

```html
const prefix = Linking.createURL('/');
  const config={
    screens:{
      Splash:{        
        screens:"Splash"    
      }
      }      
  }
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [prefix],
    config
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/deep-linking/) I'd suggest the following:

1. Check if you have the /.well-known/assetlinks.json uploaded on specific location
2. Check if you have autoVerify turned on
3. Also looking at the host, I think you should remove the *./http:// part from the host so it'll be 192.168.1.4:3000